# Batch: Need to select a file in the scripts directory (%~dp0) that has certain file extension

Tags: batch-file

Just so you know, im no wizard at writing batch scripts and I don't yet understand many things about them.

I need to select a file using the path of the batch scripts folder that has a certain file extension.

Here is what I have so far.

```
echo select vdisk file="%~dp0Test.vhd"
```

I want to be able to select this file with the path of the batch script but also not require a file name for me to select it but instead just use the file extension type so that I can change the file (with the same extension type) but the batch script will still select it.

I hope that made sense...

Comment: are you sure, there is just one `.vhd` in this folder?

Comment: Only 1 .vhd in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example gives you the best of both worlds. If you have only one `.vhd` file alongside the batch file it will be auto selected as required. If there is more than one `.vhd` file, you will be presented with a selection menu to choose the one you need.

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "%~dp0*.vhd" (CD /D "%~dp0" 2>Nul) Else Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set vhd[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For %%A In ("*.vhd") Do (Set /A i+=1 & Set "vhd[!i!]=%%~nA")
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "vhd[X]=%vhd[1]%") Else Call :Menu

Rem Example DiskPart commands using selected .vhd begin below
(   Echo select vdisk file="%~dp0%vhd[X]%.vhd"
    Echo attach vdisk)>"DPscript.txt"
DiskPart /s "DPScript.txt"
Rem Example DiskPart commands using selected .vhd end above

Exit /B

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !vhd[%%A]!)
Set /P "vhd[X]=Select a .vhd from the above list: "
If Not Defined vhd[%vhd[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "vhd[X]=!vhd[%vhd[X]%]!"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0*.vhd") do echo select vdisk file="%~dp0%%a"
```

Note: if there is more than one matching file, this will execute the command (`echo ...`) for each of them.